# Only some pages will change orientation?

Tags: android, html, mobile

Okay I'm making a mobile web app but i only want some pages to be able to change orientation, for example I want the homepage to always stay in portrait mode, but i want some of the other pages to be able to flip into landscape mode, is that possible? Thanks!
p.s. I'm using phonegap to use it as a offline app on android devices. :
)

Answer (score 0):

you can lock one activity by setting this up on the manifest xml file...

```
<activity android:name="TheActivityYouWantToLock" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
```